# subclassing QList and operator+ overloading

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to be able to add two QList objects. For example:

```
QList<int> b;
b.append(10);
b.append(20);
b.append(30);

QList<int> c;
c.append(1);
c.append(2);
c.append(3);

QList<int> d;
d = b + c;
```

For this reason, I decided to subclass the QList and to overload the operator+.

Here is my code:

```
class List : public QList<int>
{
public:
    List() : QList<int>() {}

    // Add QList + QList
    friend List operator+(const List& a1, const List& a2);
};

List operator+(const List& a1, const List& a2)
{
    List myList;

    myList.append(a1[0] + a2[0]);
    myList.append(a1[1] + a2[1]);
    myList.append(a1[2] + a2[2]);

    return myList;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    List b;
    b.append(10);
    b.append(20);
    b.append(30);

    List c;
    c.append(1);
    c.append(2);
    c.append(3);

    List d;
    d = b + c;

    List::iterator i;
    for(i = d.begin(); i != d.end(); ++i)
        qDebug() << *i;

    return a.exec();
}
```

, the result is correct but I am not sure whether this is a good approach. I would like to ask whether there is better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend overloading the `+` operator for this since `QList` already uses this operator to concatenate two lists together.  Consider creating a member function with a different name to accomplish what you're trying to do.

**Edit**
As mentioned by another answer, it's somewhat unusual to place this functionality on a derived class of a data structure, though deriving from data structures isn't *inherently* bad.

In this case, a non-member, non-friend function that accommodates lists of any size might be a more appropriate approach:

```
QList<int> addListValuesTogether(const QList<int>& a1, const QList<int>& a2)
{
   QList<int> resultingList;
   Q_ASSERT(a1.size() == a2.size());

   for (int i=0; i<a1.size(); i++)
   {
      resultingList.append(a1[i] + a2[i]);
   }

   return resultingList;
}
```

You could go further and make the above function generic (if, for example, you want the same functionality for lists containing `double` values).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ok, i will make a member function, but I am still worried whether this approach is good enough, I mean this code:
    List myList;

    myList.append(a1[0] + a2[0]);
    myList.append(a1[1] + a2[1]);
    myList.append(a1[2] + a2[2]);

    return myList;

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird approach. Better use a separate function with a clear name. You're redefining the established semantics of operator+ for QList, and subclassing containers isn't really good design either.
Looking at your code, you probably want to use a custom 3D vector class that doesn't mix list with mathematical vector semantics.

Apart from that, there are two issues in your operator+ implementation:

- You don't handle the case that the lists a1/a2 have less than three elements (critical, undefined behavior/crash), and you ignore anything beyond index 2.
- Also, when you assign to myList, it's still empty, so myList[0] etc. isn't valid.
  You need to myList.resize( 3 ) first, or use append()/push_back() instead of operator[].

Comment: Thank you for your reply. myList.resize( 3 ), yes I forgot to do that.